# print integer number from list random python

Tags: python, list, random, input

i have this little bit problem where after i generate random number to a list of 50 when i input the same number on the list, it does not print "match found". it will always send me "no match found". can you guys explain what is wrong with the code.

```
import random

mylist=[]

for i in range (50):
 x= random.randint(100,999)
 mylist.append(x)

print(mylist)

p = input('Enter an integer number: ')

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if p == mylist[i]:
        print('Match found at position')
        break
else:
    print('no match found')
```

example of output

```
[836, 569, 378, 788, 847, 584, 404, 159, 362, 271, 151, 100, 702, 414, 867, 213, 194, 553, 946, 930, 777, 143, 143, 879, 724, 752, 431, 416, 944, 509, 752, 211, 713, 951, 882, 836, 710, 998, 447, 892, 720, 210, 364, 768, 603, 456, 540, 727, 346, 153]
Enter an integer number: 836
no match found
>>>
```

i just started learning coding so if u guys can explain it i would be happy to understand for future reference  :)

Comment: `input()` returns a string, use `int()` to convert it to an integer before comparing to the numbers in the list, as in: `p = int(p)`.

Comment: `input` will return a string not an integer. You'll need to convert one or the other so that they are the same type before comparing

Comment: Also there are shorter ways to implement this. Read about `random.choices()` and `list.index()` methods.

Comment: okay thank you so much for the answer after change it to p = int(input('enter an integer number: ') works like a charm. thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

typecast your input with `int()`
then print index that match

```
import random

mylist=[]

for i in range (50):
 x= random.randint(100,999)
 mylist.append(x)

print(mylist)

p = input('Enter an integer number: ')

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if int(p) == mylist[i]:
        print('Match found at position ' + str(i))
        break
    else:
        print('no match found')
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of correcting the type cast mentioned in comments, you do not even need a loop to find the match. Use the powerful `in` in python. You can replace your entire search loop with this:

```
if int(p) in mylist:
    print('Match found at position')
else:
    print('no match found')
```

And if you need to print the index of `p` in the list, use this:

```
try: 
  print('Match found at position ',mylist.index(int(p)))
except:
  print('no match found')
```

And you can use numpy package to create a list of random integers without loop as well:

```
import numpy as np
mylist = np.random.randint(100, high=999, size=50).tolist()
```

So your entire code will look like this:

```
import numpy as np

mylist = np.random.randint(100, high=999, size=50).tolist()
p = input('Enter an integer number: ')
if int(p) in mylist:
    print('Match found at position')
else:
    print('no match found')
```